# Fantasy - book/series about moonwalker/moonpath?

Tags: story-identification, moon

I remember a middle-grade book (possibly series) that I'd read around 6th grade. Here's what I remember:

- a young female protagonist, about 10?, has an annoying brother, probably younger
- there is an evil king in the land. When the girl comes to his castle to confront him with her brother, some rebels help her dress like the king's dead daughter on purpose.
- this protagonist walks 'moon paths' or paths that appear only when the moon is at a certain phase.
- there was an important jewel in a box, a key of some sort

Help me ID this series. Was probably a tween fantasy genre sort of thing.

Edit: I was in grade 6 about 10 years ago!

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F?  We don't know how old you are, so you should tell us what year you read this book.  Also check out the other [suggestions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) to see if they help you recall anything else.

Comment: "Moon Paths" show up in Mercedes Lackey's Valdemar series (specifically the Mage Winds and Mage Storms trilogies, and possibly others), but otherwise this only has minimal similarity to the Mage Winds trilogy.

Comment: @ArcanistLupus it wasn't the Valdamar series, but thanks for introducing me to that! I will definitely be reading that!